# excel formula to put different values if different strings in cell

Tags: string, excel, search, partial

I have words coded within daily notes

These are like diary entries with coding at the end...

```
I took some advil today,tired=.5,headache=.75, etc  
rode a bike for 3 hours,tired=.75,headache=.75, etc
```

Can I write a formula that can search for the phrase tired=.5 or tired=.75 and put the .5 or .75 in the cell.  There are only 4 possibilities for levels .25,.5,.75, and 1. If it doesn't find a statement for tired it should give back 0.
This works for absolute phrase matches.

```
=IF(A1="tired=.75",.75),IF(A1="tired=.5",.5),IF(A1="tired=.25",.25)
```

but I'm not sure how to use search to do the same thing.

Here is my failed attempt at using search.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("tired=.75",B1484)),0.75,0),IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("tired=.25",B1484)),0.25,0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will do it:

```
=VALUE(MID(A1,SEARCH("tired=",A1)+6,FIND(",",(MID(A1,SEARCH("tired=",A1),12)))-6-1))
```

No reason to use IF statements, just FIND and convert the text directly.  I mix FIND and SEARCH here, you can use one or both as you prefer (FIND is case sensitive, SEARCH is not).

Comment: Good Idea...So basically you are finding the value of the text between the = sign and the next comma. I just have to make sure it ends in comma. I don't think there's another option besides that.  What about the case where tired is not marked at all it should give 0 instead it gives #value. Can I wrap the whole thing in something that gives 0 if nothing is found? But the same answer if something is found?

Comment: Assuming you're on a newish version of office, the IFERROR function is probably most useful for this - odds are you'll get an error if nothing is found (since Excel tends towards returning errors that way), and IFERROR does just what you want there - IFERROR(forumla,value-if-error) returns formula's result if valid, otherwise value-if-error.  If you don't have IFERROR, you can directly evaluate the result like in the olden days (IF(formula=error, value-if-error, formula), but it requires putting the formula in twice...

Comment: Thanks for your expertise. I'm confident I can get this to work now.

Comment: I'm using the IFERROR solution but running into a problem where tired=.5 is often followed by a space not a comma.  How would I allow it to handle both cases comma or space. I'm trying to use OR with IFERROR casecomma, and IFERROR, casespace. but not sure how to implement it.